# How to embed local file in discordgo InteractionRespond?

Tags: discord, bots, discordgo

I want to respond to a user with a locally stored video.

This is as far as I got. There does not seem to be way to use a local path as I get a
`{"code": "URL_TYPE_INVALID_URL", "message": "Not a well formed URL."}` error message while trying to use a local path.

```
s.InteractionRespond(i.Interaction, &discordgo.InteractionResponse{
    Type: discordgo.InteractionResponseChannelMessageWithSource,
    Data: &discordgo.InteractionResponseData{
        Embeds: []*discordgo.MessageEmbed{
            {
                Type: discordgo.EmbedTypeVideo,
                Video: &discordgo.MessageEmbedVideo{
                    URL: "<PATH_TO_MY_FILE>",
                },
            },
        },
    },
})
```

I know that it can be done in JS with Discord.js's *AttachmentBuilder* and wonder if maybe there is some kind of equivalent of that in discordgo.

Comment: If anyone is still searching for an answer, here is a solution https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo/issues/1451